# Save Multiple docker images into one tar.gz file with maven fabric8 plugin

Tags: fabric8, docker-maven-plugin, fabric8-maven-plugin

We are using `io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.27.2` to build docker images.

my maven project consist of 3 modules (`module1`, `module2` and `module3`). Each module builds a docker image based on the dockerfile present within each module.

Now, when I run `mvn docker:save` - I want to save all 3 docker images into one tar.gz file, `myproject-1.0.0.tar.gz`. Is it even possible with this plugin?

**My Project Structure:**

```
project
|-module1
  |-DockerFile1
  |-pom.xml
|-module2
  |-DockerFile2
  |-pom.xml
|-module3
  |-DockerFile3
  |-pom.xml
|-pom.xml
```

I'm using io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.27.2

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
 <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>0.27.2</version>
 . . .
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save all images independly and then use maven assembly plugin to pack them in one file.

According to the [documentation](http://dmp.fabric8.io/#docker:save): you can save only one image in archive using this plugin. But you can execute docker:save for all needed images (it will create a few archives). And than assemble them.