# Fabric8 Maven Plugin - How to pass --rm into build options?

Tags: fabric8, fabric8-maven-plugin

We are using `io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.27.2` to build our docker images.

Just wondering how to pass `rm` into buildoptions? I want to clear all the intermediate (<none>) images after successfully building them - using the `mvn docker:build` command

```
REPOSITORY            TAG       IMAGE ID         CREATED             SIZE
myproject/baseimage   latest    baa18e544738     3 days ago          1.53GB
<none>                <none>    c98ecb5bc381     3 days ago          784MB
<none>                <none>    14d3f81c4bc0     4 days ago          533MB
<none>                <none>    9b07174fc67a     4 days ago          532MB
```

I tried to pass something like this.

```
<buildoptions>
   <rm>true</rm>
</buildoptions>
```

equivalent of:

```
docker build --rm -f Dockerfile -t myproject/baseImage:latest .
```

The documentation is not very clear ->  http://dmp.fabric8.io/#build-configuration

**Full Configuration of pom.xml:**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.27.2</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <name>myproject/baseimage</name>
                        <build>
                            <tags>
                                <tag>latest</tag>
                            </tags>
                            <dockerFile>${project.basedir}/Dockerfile</dockerFile>
                            <buildOptions>
                                <rm>true</rm>
                            </buildOptions>
                        </build>
                    </image>
                </images>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>docker:build</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried a bunch of things including passing the same variable in maven properties. But nothing worked.

```
<docker.buildoptions.rm>true</docker.buildoptions.rm>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in documentation, there is an enum `cleanup` which removes dangling (untagged) images after each build (including any containers created from them). It can be set to `true`, `false` and `try` which tries to remove the old image, but doesn’t fail the build if this is not possible because e.g. the image is still used by a running container. You can set it in your build configuration like:

```
<build>
   <from>${image}</from>
   <labels>
      <dmp.version>${project.version}</dmp.version>
      <dmp.name>${project.artifactId}</dmp.name>
   </labels>
   <assembly>
      <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
   </assembly>

   ...

   <cleanup>true</cleanup>  
</build>
```

Comment: hmm... `cleanup`  doesn't work. It still leaves all the <none> images. Mine is a multi-module maven project - Each one builds its own image. Not sure if that's causing any issues.

Comment: ah, What happens when you do it for a single module individually? Could you please share your project if possible?

Comment: Hi @Rohan, Ok, I'll try that. I posted another question related to fabricio8 plugin -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909282/save-multiple-docker-images-into-one-tar-gz-file-with-maven-fabric8-plugin. Where I tried to describe my full project structure. Can you take a look at that? Hopefully that should give you an idea of what my project is. Unfortunately, I can't post the actual source code as it's not open source.